# How to use the Async library with Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I try to import the Async library in my Angular 2 (2.0.0-rc.1) application without success. https://github.com/caolan/async#es-modules

I get the following error:

```
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:3003/traceur 404 (Not Found)
(index):31 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3003/traceur(…)
```

Here's what I did:

```
npm install async-es --save
```

In "systemjs.config.js":

```
(function (global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        // ...
        'async-es': 'node_modules/async-es'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        // ...
        'async-es': { main: 'index.js', 'defaultExtension': 'js' }
    };

    // ...

    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

In "my.component.ts":

```
import {async} from 'async-es';
```

I tried to import it by doing like the importing of others libraries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the version of Angular2 you use is a bit old (alpha). You should use a beta or rc one.

Here is the configuration in your main HTML file:

```
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err);  });
</script>
```

and the content of the `systemjs.config.js` one:

```
var map = {
  'app': 'app', // 'dist',
  'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
  '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular'
};

var packages = {
  'app': { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
};

var packageNames = [
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/router-deprecated',
  '@angular/testing',
  '@angular/upgrade',
];

packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
  packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

var config = {
  map: map,
  packages: packages
}

if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

System.config(config);
```

See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: My version of Angular is 2.0.0-beta.16. But in fact, it evolved in recent days.  Do you think that doing the update, this will solve my problem?

Comment: I still have the same error after updating. Angular 2.0.0-rc.1. I'll update my initial post.